# Deployment of Tomcat7 WAR

Tags: tomcat

I ran `dpkg -l tomcat 7 | grep webapp` to find the directory where to place my WAR file.

When I dumped my ROOT.war to this directory, the corresponding ROOT directory was populated (exploded is the term, I think).

Then, I restarted (stop, then start) tomcat.

However, I navigated to localhost on port 8080, but I had the same default Apache homepage.

Please advise.

Comment: Do you mean you want to make your web application be the Tomcat default app?

Comment: I just want to know how to view my webapp from Firefox. localhost on port 8080 doesn't work. I tried localhost/ROOT on port 8080 too, but that failed.

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application.3F

Comment: Did you remove the existing directory called "ROOT" before dumping ROOT.war ?

Comment: Yes, I removed the existing ROOT directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, absent any other configuration, it would be `http://localhost:8080/NAMEOFYOURWEBAPP`

Comment: I browsed to localhost:8080 with my ROOT.war, and was able to view my Tomcat-hosted webapp. Yesterday I might've failed to run memcached. Since my app depends on it, then maybe that's why it did not start in Tomcat.